# Is it possible for a function called from within an object to have access to that object's scope?

Tags: javascript

I can't think of a way to explain what I'm after more than I've done in the title, so I'll repeat it. Is it possible for an anonymous function called from within an object to have access to that object's scope? The following code block should explain what I'm trying to do better than I can:

```
function myObj(testFunc) {
    this.testFunc = testFunc;


    this.Foo = function Foo(test) {
        this.test = test;

        this.saySomething = function(text) {
            alert(text);
        };
    };

    var Foo = this.Foo;

    this.testFunc.apply(this);
}

var test = new myObj(function() {
    var test = new Foo();
    test.saySomething("Hello world");
});
```

When I run this, I get an error: "Foo is not defined." How do I ensure that `Foo` will be defined when I call the anonymous function? [Here's a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/grzUd/4/) for further experimentation.

**Edit**: I am aware of the fact that adding the line `var Foo = this.Foo;` to the anonymous function I pass in to my instance of `myObj` will make this work. However, I'd like to avoid having to expose the variable inside the anonymous function--do I have any other options?.

Comment: Note that using named function expressions like `this.Foo = function Foo(test)` can cause [significant issues in IE](http://kangax.github.com/nfe/), just don't do it.

Comment: @RobG: I was given that pattern by an answer to another question of mine, and wasn't aware that it caused a problem. Thanks for pointing that out! Are there any ways I can reproduce the behavior of named functions? (I.e. an object within an object)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Should be `this.Foo`:

```
var test = new myObj(function() {
    var test = new this.Foo();
    test.saySomething("Hello world");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/grzUd/5/

Or alternatively using `with`:

```
var test = new myObj(function() {
    with (this) {
        var test = new Foo();
        test.saySomething("Hello world");
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/grzUd/6/

Comment: I know, and I should have clarified, but I'd like to avoid having to use `this` inside of the anonymous function for reasons I've highlighted in my updated question.

Comment: @ElliotBonneville cannot be done then. You can't expose a local scope outside of a local scope. Hence the point behind local scopes.

Comment: Ah, okay. I guess I'll have to use one of the answers to this question, then. Thanks for clearing this up.

Answer (score 2):

Change `var test = new Foo();` to `var test = new this.Foo();`.

***Edit:*** Or you could pass it as a parameter.

```
function myObj(testFunc) {
    this.testFunc = testFunc;

    var Foo = function (test) {
        this.test = test;
        this.saySomething = function(text) {
            alert(text);
        };
    };

    this.testFunc(Foo);
}

var test = new myObj(function(Foo) {
    var test = new Foo();
    test.saySomething("Hello world");
});
```

Comment: See my comment on Petah's answer.

Comment: @ElliotBonneville You could only access `Foo` through `this` or pass it as a parameter as my edited answer.

Comment: @xdazz—you know `this.testFunc.call(this, Foo)` is the same as `this.testFunc(Foo)` don't you?

Comment: @RobG Yep, you are write. Changed from `this.testFunc.apply(this);` made that code :)

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be confused about the difference between identifier resolution on the scope chain and property resolution.

*Foo* is a **property** of an instance of *myObj* (i.e. it's an object property). Calling `new Foo` will resolve *Foo* as a variable on the scope chain, which isn't the right place to look for it. That's why Petah's answer tries to use *with*, to put the object properties of the *this* object on the scope chain.

Comment: No, I think I understand the concept properly, since my understanding of the whole "thing" is basically what you explained. However, I appreciate the time you took to answer my question. +1