# How dangerous is modifying a function directly?

Tags: javascript

To get around what has proven to be a scope limitation to me (as answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11388429/is-it-possible-for-a-function-called-from-within-an-object-to-have-access-to-tha/11388441#11388441)), I've written a piece of code which inserts a line in an anonymous function so that whoever writes the function doesn't have to do it themselves. It's a bit hacky (actually, it feels quite a lot hacky), and I really don't know what I'm doing, so I'd appreciate an expert eye to catch any errors I may have missed or point out any dangers I'm unaware of. Here's the code:

```
function myObj(testFunc) {
    this.testFunc = testFunc;


    this.Foo = function Foo(test) {
        this.test = test;

        this.saySomething = function(text) {
            alert(text);
        };
    };

    var Foo = this.Foo;
    var funcSep = this.testFunc.toString().split("{");
    funcSep.splice(0, 1);
    funcSep = funcSep.join("{");
    var compFunc =  "    var Foo = this.Foo;" + funcSep;
    compFunc = compFunc.split("}");
    compFunc.splice(compFunc.length - 1, 1);
    compFunc.join("}");
    var otherTestFunc = new Function(compFunc);
    otherTestFunc.apply(this);
}

var test = new myObj(function() {
    var test = new Foo();
    test.saySomething("Hello world");
});
```

The function above evaluates as expected, and I don't need to force whoever writes the anonymous function to obtain access to `Foo` by using `this.Foo`. This approach feels iffy, though. Is what I'm doing acceptable, and if not, are there any ways to circumvent it?

Also, the only reason I didn't include this in my original question is that seems like something of a departure from the original context of the question.

Comment: Just a tip: this breaks with builtins (JSON.stringify, Array.prototype.splice, etc.) not that they will need access to Foo. As for the question, I think a more appropriate way to do it would be to pass Foo into their function, or require the function writers to explicitly call this.Foo (I'd encourage the latter)

Comment: Ah, okay, thanks. I'll see if that has any effect on the method. I'd make Foo global if I could (ideally, I'd be able to, but this is intended to become part of a library and I'd like to have as little of a footprint on the global object as I can), and failing that, make it so that the function writers can access it as plain Foo. If you can point out a concrete reason to use `this.Foo`, I will switch over. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Also note this is effectively the same as `eval` which is not that great.  I'd suggest some googling about the problems with `eval` in javascript.

Comment: I'm well aware of the problems with `eval` -- however, I'm not worried about them, because I will only ever have friendly code being passed in. Unless of course a developer decides he wants to sabotage himself. :-)

Comment: One other thing (I'm having a hard time with wording on this response so please note I am trying to not be condescending! Tone is so difficult on the internet): You note that you want to avoid polluting globals with your library, yet injecting a variable definition into someone's function is akin to polluting their global scope (although it is scope limited).  For an example, `jQuery` has a bunch of wonderful constructors (`Event`, `Deferred`, etc.) that would be great, but are better left as `$.Event`, etc...

Comment: (Noted, and I have a feeling that I'm coming across as slightly rude myself--something I certainly don't intend to do!) The only reason I want to do this is because `Foo` will be called many many times (indeed, it's one of the core constructors in my library), and it would require a lot more typing and clutter up the functions to require `this`. By injecting the variable definition, I'm at least avoiding polluting the scope outside of the function. That's really the best I can do, as I see it. It's quite the difficult design decision.

Comment: Agreed, you could also suggest the shortening to the end-developer, but unfortunately I don't see any other ways to do this cleanly :/

Comment: Well, as it stands, I will stick with this method (it's really as clean as I can make it). If somebody suggests something else, I'd gladly take their advice, of course. Appreciate your time! If you post a quick answer containing a summary of what you said here I'll accept and upvote it. Thanks once more.

Comment: I'll wait a bit, mine is more of a non-answer at the moment :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to break the language. Don't do that. It's not Java.

Developers have certain expectations on the behaviour and scope of variables, and your approach would rather confuse them. Think about the following:

```
var Foo = SomeWonderfulClass;    
var test = new myObj(function() {
    var test = new Foo();
    // ...
});
```

Now the developer wants to instantiate `SomeWonderfulClass`, but your magic messes around with that.

On the other hand, this would work fine, even with your trickery:

```
var test = new myObj(function() {
    var Foo = SomeWonderfulClass;    
    var test = new Foo();
    // ...
});
```

But the bigger problem is that the actual scope is lost:

```
var Bananas = SomeWonderfulClass;
var test = new myObj(function() {
    var test = new Bananas(); // Error: Bananas is undefined!
});
```

Nobody expects such shenanigans.

---

That being said, there's some things about your code to be improved:

- `this.Foo` is initialized with every new object. That's not necessary. Better use

  ```
  myObj.prototype.Foo = function () {...}
  ```
- The line `var Foo = this.Foo;` is not needed in `myObj`.
- Your string magic is overly complex. How about

  ```
  var otherTestFunc = new Function(testFunc.toString()
          .replace(/^[^{]+{/, '{var Foo=this.Foo;'));
  ```

  No need to remove the braces.
- (`testFunc` does not accept any arguments, but I guess you know that.)

So that boils down to

```
function myObj(testFunc) {
    this.testFunc = testFunc;
    var otherTestFunc = new Function(testFunc.toString()
            .replace(/^[^{]+{/, '{var Foo=this.Foo;'));
    otherTestFunc.apply(this);
}

myObj.prototype.Foo = function Foo(test) {
    this.test = test;

    this.saySomething = function(text) {
        alert(text);
    };
};
```

Comment: Excellent answer, thank you. Are there any alternatives other than to force the end developers to use `this.Foo` to gain access to Foo? If not, I will accept this answer.

Comment: I think there's no reasonable alternative. (And I don't think typing 5 characters will kill anyone either :))

Comment: Ah, okay. Haha, that's true, but as I mentioned in a previous comment, `Foo` is a core function in my library and will be called quite a few times. Oh well, I'll see what I can figure out. Since you mentioned my method breaking global scope, I went and tested it--you're right. I've abandoned it. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I've been bothered by this method since I saw it in asp.net validation code (!). Not really safe for arbitrary function:

```
var f = (function () {
   var closure = 1
   return function (argument) {
      alert(argument)
      alert(closure)
   }
})()

var f2 = new Function(f.toString().replace(/^function.*?{([\s\S]*)}$/, 'alert(1);$1'))
f2(1) // :(
```

Arguments could be saved though.